# How do i view the SQL generated by EntityFramework Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for something simple so any monkey like me can understand and implement it easily. If it's possible i only want to see the SQL queries and no extra code or commentaries that could confuse me.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i view the SQL generated by EntityFramework Core?

You can try to set [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#aspnet-core-and-ef-core-categories) to `Debug` in `appsettings.json` to log EF events.

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Debug code and check the generated SQL query in **Output** window.

[image]